# add sharethis button to a slideshow

Tags: javascript, social-network

I'm trying to add a button Sharethis to a slideshow "views_slideshow" that shows the whole content to the specific element in the slideshow.
the problem is I can't add this button to the slideshow, and I have it to show inside a block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, you just add "shareThis" to your content type you want this to show in a slide show, and since we are showing the whole content it will show with the rest of the node.